# How to know if wpf app is in terminal services session?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

Is there an equivalent to

**SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession** in wpf?

I want to know if the current wpf application is running in a terminal server session.
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need a special version for WPF? What prevents you to call it in a WPF application?

Comment: Sorry..I should have mentioned this but we dont hav a reference to that dll..I guess we could add it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the SystemParameters class  to query system settings, especially the [SystemParameters.IsRemoteSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.isremotesession.aspx) property to get a value that indicates whether the calling process is associated with a Terminal Services client session (like SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession property).

Answer (score 1):

Just add a reference to System.Windows.Forms   Since you are not messing with the UI you don't need anything special.

```
  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession.ToString());
```